# Filter or function in TWIG?

Tags: symfony, twig

When should some functionality be created as a filter instead of a function and vice versa?

```
user | function
```

vs

```
function(user)
```

Someone pointed out the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#extending-twig), however it does not explain when to use which. It does say this:

> Functions support the same features as filters, except for the
>   pre_escape and preserves_safety options.

What is the point of twig support function if they behave just like a filter?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**A filter** is a way to transform the displayed data. 
For example if you want to display the content of a variable `L1K3 Th1s`, you'll have to write a `filter` (example : `{{ username|l33t }}`)

**A function** is used when you need to compute things to render the result. 
For example, the `{{ dump(username) }}` function which will call internally the `var_dump` php function.

Usually you write a function when you need to do heavier things than just simply transform the display of a content in a simple way.

Comment: In addition a Twig function can have multiple arguments. So if you need that your choice is easy.

Comment: Filters can have multiple arguments as well, so this facet alone is not necessarily determinant.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add that **functions** could make more sense where the code you want to execute has no input you can supply from within the Twig template.

Say you wanted to show a warning if you detect an unsupported browser based on the User Agent. Assuming you don't have the variable holding the User Agent at hand, you could use a `TwigFunction` like this:

```
{% if not supportedBrowser() %} ... {% endif%}
```

If you did have the User Agent available in any variable in the current Twig scope, you could use a filter and call it like this:

```
{% if not app.request.headers.get('user-agent')|supportedBrowser %} ... {% endif %}
```

The above would work if your Twig template ran in a Symfony application.

---

With all that said, if you had the User Agent in a local variable, filter may not be the best approach. You could write a [Twig Test](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html#tests) and use it like this:

```
{% if app.request.headers.get('user-agent') is not supportedBrowser %} ... {% endif %}
```

I know this veers away from the original question, but I think it is important to be aware of a "C" option, when considering "A or B".

As a personal opinion, using a Twig Test in this particular context is easier to read/understand as it converts the underlying logic into plain language.

Comment: Completely forgot about twig tests, but it was exactly what I needed!